# .NET WebApi breaks when url ends with ampersand

Tags: c#, url, asp.net-web-api2

I have an ApiController - for example 'Home' controller, with action 'Test' which accepts two parameters - test1 and test2, both with default values

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
public ActionResult Test(int test1 = 3, int test2 = 5)
{
    var a = 0;
    return null;
}
```

Now when I call **Home/Test?test1=1**, everything is OK.
But when I call **Home/Test?test1=1&**, the server throws exception

> *The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'test2' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method
>   'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Test(Int32, Int32)' in
>   'TestAPI.Controllers.ValuesController'. An optional parameter must be
>   a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional
>   parameter.*

My route configuration is currently like this:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

This also happens on a brand new WebApi project so it is not something from my configuration. 
The big problem is that this ampersand comes from a client project and I cannot change it there, although I am aware that this is a bad request.

The strangest thing is that if Home controller is inheriting Controller instead of ApiController - everything is fine.

**Edit 1** 
I forgot to mention that if I make the parameters nullable (i.e. int?) then the error dissapears but test2 has value of null instead of 5 when calling the bad URL, so this is not an option for me.

Comment: You just told the server that you have another parameter (that's what & means), yet *didn't* supply any parameter. It's not Web API that breaks. The error message clearly explains how to fix this - use a nullable parameter. Change the type to `int?`

Comment: Using `int?` *is* an option. Just use `test2??5` in your code, eg `var actualTest2 = test2 ?? 5;`

Comment: Is a URI ending with an `&` even valid per the spec?

Comment: I know that I do not supply parameter when the server expects one, but when using MVC Controller the server understands the request. I have many many actions in the application and I did not want to start checking every single parameter for correct value.

Comment: @Amy yes it's valid.

Comment: You are arguing that ASP.NET should interpret the ampersand as the beginning of a new key-value pair, even if none is actually supplied. But one could just aswell argue, that a since there is no key-value pair following the ampersand, it should be interpreted as part of the previous value. Which is obviously what, in fact, happens. ASP.NET thinks the supplied value is `1&`, and when it can't parse it as an int, it fails. You can probably hook some code in some place, to change this behaviour. But to be honest, the easiest solution by far, is just to not have trailing ampersands in requests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a custom `DelegatingHandler` and remove trailing '&':

```
public class SanitizeHandler : System.Net.Http.DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if (request.RequestUri.ToString().EndsWith("&"))
            request.RequestUri = new Uri(request.RequestUri.ToString().TrimEnd('&'));

        return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

Register the new Handler in `Application_Start`:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.MessageHandlers.Add(new SanitizeHandler());
```

Or add it to your `HttpConfiguration`(then it is only called with Webapi calls):

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    ...
    config.MessageHandlers.Add(new SanitizeHandler());
    ...   
}
```

Comment: Or similar meaning Owin middleware (if it is Owin based Web Api).

Comment: I was hoping about something simpler but this will work too. Thanks!